# Why can I not receive email for new Exchange email user?

Tags: windows-server-2003

1. I created a new user for MS
   Exchange.
2. I can send and receive  email from
   other members of the companies
   server domain.
3. I can send outbound email to
   anywhere outside the company without
   a problem.
4. However I can’t receive email from a
   outside the local AD Domain
   Controller.
5. Is this a Server or a Firewall
   issue?

Comment: I received this error from my external email account!

Diagnostic-Code: smtp;550 No such user - psmtp

Comment: I went to the Exhange server and removed the mailbox user from active directory. I went to Advanced Mangement to recreate the users' mailbox under AD. Same results. This is a SBS 2003 server.
I think everything is set correctly on my server. The PC users custom config for email options and it does not show MS Outlook as an option. Any suggestions on adding outlook to Set Programs Access and default list?

Answer (score 1):

Is this for a particular user or all users?

If for a Particular User:
If you go to the user from 'Active Directory Users and Computers' go to there properties and then the 'Exchange General tab' and then 'Delivery Restrictions'.  Is Accept messages 'from authenticated users only' checked?

If For All Users:
If you go the SMTP Virtual Server Properties though the 'Exchange System Manager' and the click the 'Access' tab and go to Authentication, is 'Anonymous Access' Enabled?

Test from Outside Using Telnet:
Try to telnet to it from the outside somewhere:

```
telnet mailServerIp 25
elho
Mail From: Foo@foo.com
RCPT TO: emailThatIsNotWorking@myDomain.com
DATA
Foo
.
```

Comment: The new user is the only PC  having this email issue.
To answer your question.....
"If you go to the user from 'Active Directory Users and Computers' go to there properties and then the 'Exchange General tab' and then 'Delivery Restrictions'. Is Accept messages 'from authenticated users only' checked? "……..Its unchecked

I noticed that the other users have a logon.bat script and a user profile setup to set their rights.  Maybe the previous Administrator set the email rules in the logon script?

Comment: I will try to telnet from the outside later

Comment: I went to the Exhange server and removed the mailbox user from active directory. I went to Advanced Mangement to recreate the users' mailbox under AD. Same results. This is a SBS 2003 server. I think everything is set correctly on my server. The PC users custom config for email options and it does not show MS Outlook as an option. Any suggestions on adding outlook to Set Programs Access and default list? – Greg 0

Answer (score 0):

Check the user's properties, the email address tab and see if there is an SMTP address there for the user.

if it's missing, add it, that will get them working.

For the future, you'll want to look into the default for the domain, usually this is setup in a default setting in the exchange server.  Reciepent policy I think, you'll what to check the default and see if it's missing the SMTP for the domain.

Comment: I checked SMTP and it is added so that's not it. The server is a Windows Small Busness 2003 edition. It combines Active Directory into MSExchange along with WINS and DNS. Since only one user is having this issue the entire Domain won't be affected.

Comment: Could there be an entry in the \\server\profiles\user directory that enables SMTP?

Comment: I am almost there! I looked at the Recipient policy advanced. SMTP is the default as you said, but in advanced tab a radio button says the recipient receive is determined by a user profile. So I think need to create a user profile the points to the default SMTP.

Comment: Reporting-MTA: dns;col0-omc1-s5.col0.hotmail.com
Received-From-MTA: dns;COL101-W42
Arrival-Date: Wed, 12 Aug 2009 09:14:05 -0700
Still fails!
Final-Recipient: rfc822;greg@sgmedical.com
Action: failed
Status: 5.5.0
Diagnostic-Code: smtp;550 No such user - psmtp
I am stumped I still belive its on the Mail Server

Comment: I went to the Exhange server and removed the mailbox user from active directory. I went to Advanced Mangement to recreate the users' mailbox under AD. Same results. This is a SBS 2003 server. I think everything is set correctly on my server. The PC users custom config for email options and it does not show MS Outlook as an option. Any suggestions on adding outlook to Set Programs Access and default list? – Greg 0

Answer (score 0):

Based on your follow-up comment, it sounds like you're using Postini (now Google) for spam filtering on this domain. You will need to tell Postini about the new mailbox before they will be able to receive mail.

Next step: tracking down your Postini admin credentials. Good luck!

I believe you'll need to start here: https://login.postini.com/exec/login

more info on password resets here: https://www.postini.com/support/login_help.php